# iTunes : App Upload Warning : The app references non-public selectors in :setRefreshInterval

Tags: ios, itunes, non-public-selectors

While uploading the binary app to iTunes, it reports warning as follows:

> The app references non-public selectors in :setRefreshInterval

- How can I solve this issue?
- Which public API can resolve the issue (:setRefreshInterval) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you have used a private API, not a documented/public one. Apple will generally reject your app if you use this because they are not permitted and if Apple changes the internal system (included this undocumented code) it can crash your app.
And people would leave negative reviews.

In this case `setRefreshInterval:` is the private method so what does `setRefreshInterval:` do in your code, then maybe I can give you alternatives...

I'm pretty sure to check if you are using a public API: there is no auto completion and another thing is press alt and click the method/property to see if it has documentation

Comment: is there any command line tool or any app or any system to check whether any undocumented code is available at my code?

Answer (score 1):

This means that the validation has spotted an invocation of some private API in your app. Take a look in that method mentioned in the warning and see if there is anything there that is not permitted. Once you've found it, try to accomplish the same thing using public APIs.

Comment: Which public API can resolve the issue? regarding :setRefreshInterval

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find that selector in the iOS public API.  I found it in the MacOS NSTimeInterval class.  And even though that selector could work in iOS, since it's not public, you can't use it in an iOS app if you plan to push that app to the AppStore.